# php scripts with curl or file_get_contents results in ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in MacOSX Mojave

Tags: php, curl, macos-mojave

I recently upgraded on to MacOsx mojave then, suddenly php script not working anymore. if I use real urls, but if I use localhost it works.

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```

results in

> This page isn’t working mysite.localhost didn’t send any data.
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Works:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://localhost/');
```

Tests:
Chrome,Firefox,Safari

XAMPP
PHP5.6.33 
OSX: Mojave

Comment: I have the same issue, did you solve your issue in the meantime?

Comment: Okay, so far I found out, that this error only appears for me, if I have the PDFlib library included. Without it everything works fine. I guess that is why nobody really has a similar issue. Let's wait if there is a fix in a future version upgrade.

Comment: Adding "unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" at the of /xamppfiles/bin/envvars solved the issue.